# Using 'supplement' as a verb

Tags: verbs

Recently I had to write an application letter, and when my teacher examined it; he marked the following sentence as incorrect (because of the supposedly wrong usage of 'supplement')

> I would like to supplement my theoretical knowledge with practical knowledge, in accordance with your motto: 'learning by doing'.

I couldn't find supplement as a verb in my Dutch-English dictionairy, but various sources online say it can also be used as a verb. In this case, was I wrong? And if so, what would be the appropriate verb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not wrong.

> Supplement (verb /ˈsʌplɪˌmɛnt/)
>
> To provide a supplement to, esp in order to remedy a deficiency

This Google NGram shows that it's use as a verb is reasonably commonplace, and has been for a while:

[image]

To my native-English ears, "supplement my knowledge"  sounds entirely valid, and indeed commonplace, particularly for use on a CV, and so I would venture to suggest that your teacher is just straightforwardly wrong.

Comment: Guest1337, Your sentence sounds okay to me. Perhaps your teacher thought the word supplement sounds more like diet/vitamin pills?

Comment: I don't really see the point of that NGram. [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22data+supplement+our%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are a few instances of *[the] data supplement [our previous findings]*, for example, but almost all the instances contributing to your chart will in fact be using the word *supplement* as a ***noun*** (forming part of a compound noun phrase where it's modified by another noun *data*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That was the whole point of the NGram. The blue line shows supplement used as a verb. The red line is a base line where it is used as a noun to show that supplement used as a verb is commonplace.

Comment: @Matt: oic. It might have been better to graph [supplemented,a supplement](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=supplemented%2Ca+supplement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), which unambiguously shows verb and noun forms (and apparently shows that the verb form arose much later, but is now far more common than the noun usage).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks. I've altered the ngram to use your suggestion.

Comment: @Matt♦: Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery! (have my previously-withheld upvote! :)